# Struct initialization in SwiftUI: 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass a Binding to my VM which is supposed to be a filter so the VM fetches objects according to the filtering passed by params.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to initialize the VM, as I'm getting the error `'self' used before all stored properties are initialized` in the line where I'm initializing my VM `self.jobsViewModel = JobsViewModel(jobFilter: $jobFilter)`

```
struct JobsTab: View {
    @ObservedObject var jobsViewModel: JobsViewModel
    @ObservedObject var categoriesViewModel: CategoriesViewModel
    
    @StateObject var searchText: SearchText = SearchText()
    
    @State private var isEditing: Bool
    @State private var showFilter: Bool
    @State private var jobFilter: JobFilter
    
    init() {
        self.categoriesViewModel = CategoriesViewModel()
        self.jobFilter = JobFilter(category: nil)
        self.showFilter = false
        self.isEditing = false
        self.jobsViewModel = JobsViewModel(jobFilter: $jobFilter)
    }
```

I think I'm initializing all the vars, and `self.searchText` isn't in the init block because the compiler complains that it is a get-only property.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my VM:

```
class JobsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
    @Published var jobs: [Jobs] = []
    @Binding var jobFilter: JobFilter
    
    init(jobFilter: Binding<JobFilter>) {
        _jobFilter = jobFilter
    }
...
}

struct JobFilter {
    var category: Category?
}
```

My idea was to have the job filter as a state in the JobsTab, and every time that state changes, the VM would try to fetch the jobs that match the `JobFilter`

Comment: You are accessing the value before initialization, but even if you had no issue that would bad idea doing things in initialization, you can use on appear

Comment: thanks a lot for the prompt answer! what do you mean with `onAppear`? where should I do that, in the `JobsTab` or in the `JobsViewModel`?

Comment: I prefer the pattern where you inject the ViewModelError from the super view. You should probably inject a `JobsTabViewModel` which you have initialised with a `JobsModel` and a `CategoriesModel` or something; this view shouldn't know anything about other views viewmodels

Comment: Using a custom init as you are does not work well in SwiftUI. Stay away from custom inits. Your Viewmodels are likely leaking and your state variables are not being initialized properly. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Like Paul said injection is even better! If your project requirements let you this option, other way is onAppear for safety you can use combination of a condition and completion handler, if you need more information let me know.

Comment: @Cristik sorry about that; I've added it now to the original question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't create `@ObservedObject` values in your initializer. Doing so leads to bugs, because you'll create new instances every time the view is recreated. Either `jobsViewModel` and `categoriesViewModel` should be passed as arguments to `init`, or  you should be using `@StateObject` for those properties.

But anyway, you actually asked: why can't we use `$jobFilter` before initializing `jobsViewModel`?

Let's start by simplifying the example:

```swift
struct JobsTab: View {
    @State var jobFilter: String
    var jobFilterBinding: Binding<String>

    init() {
        jobFilter = ""
        jobFilterBinding = $jobFilter
                       //  ^  'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
    }

    var body: some View { Text("hello") }
}
```

So, what's going on here? It'll help if we “de-sugar” the use of `@State`. The compiler transforms the declaration of `jobFilter` into three properties:

```swift
struct JobsTab: View {
    private var _jobFilter: State<String>

    var jobFilter: String {
        get { _jobFilter.wrappedValue }
        nonmutating set { _jobFilter.wrappedValue = newValue }
    }

    var $jobFilter: Binding<String> {
        get { _jobFilter.projectedValue }
    }

    var jobFilterBinding: Binding<String>

    init() {
        _jobFilter = State<String>(wrappedValue: "")
        jobFilterBinding = $jobFilter
                       //  ^  'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
    }

    var body: some View { Text("hello") }
}
```

Notice now that `$jobFilter` is not a stored property. It is a computed property. So accessing `$jobFilter` means calling its “getter”, which is a method on `self`. But we cannot call a method on `self` until `self` is fully initialized. That's why we get an error if we try to use `$jobFilter` before initializing all stored properties.

The fix is to avoid using `$jobFilter`. Instead, we can use `_jobFilter.projectedValue` directly:

```swift
struct JobsTab: View {
    @State var jobFilter: String
    var jobFilterBinding: Binding<String>

    init() {
        jobFilter = ""
        jobFilterBinding = _jobFilter.projectedValue
    }

    var body: some View { Text("hello") }
}
```

Comment: With giving the right answer for wrong method, he would be confused!